# Why is the primitive of $f(ax+b)$ equal to $\frac 1a\cdot F(ax+b)+C$

Tags: integration

I need to make solve the following problem: $\int \sqrt{4x-1}$. I do know what the answer is, but I had to use the following rule:

$$\int f(ax+b)=\frac 1aF(ax+b)+C$$

Why is this rule correct?

Comment: Well, what's the derivative of the RHS?

Comment: The chain rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$J(x)=\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{1}{a}F(ax+b)+C) \text{ by sum rule we have } J(x)=\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{1}{a}F(ax+b))+\frac{d}{dx}(C) \text{ and by constant rule we have }J(x)= \frac{d}{dx}(\frac{1}{a}F(ax+b)) \text{ and by constant multiple rule we have } J(x)=\frac{1}{a} \frac{d}{dx}F(ax+b) \text{ and by chain rule we have }J(x)= \frac{1}{a}(ax+b)'f(ax+b) \text{ and we know } (ax+b)'=a \text{ so we have } J(x)=\frac{1}{a}(a)f(ax+b)=f(ax+b) $

Answer (score 1):

You Substitute $y=ax+b$ and then $dy = adx$, hence: $dx= \frac{dy}{a}$. $a$ is a constant that you can take out the integral; you use $\int f(y)dy = F(y)$, resubstitute.