# The integral of $\sin (x/2)$?

Tags: calculus, integration

From what I'm solving the integral of $\sin(x/2)$ is $-\cos(x/2)$ but, whenever I check the answer the correct integral is $-2\cos(x/2)$. I don't know where I'm wrong.

Please, help.

Comment: Did you remember to think about the chain rule?

Comment: Recall that$$ (-2\cos(x/2))'=-2(-\sin(x/2))(1/2)$$

Comment: On which interval are you integrating?

Comment: I'm actually doing it from "Thomas Calculus". The question  is "integral of xsin(x/2)". I just can't figure out how I calculate the integral of sin(x/2)

Comment: [Why is the primitive of $f(ax+b)$ equal to $\frac 1a\cdot F(ax+b)+C$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1141107/why-is-the-primitive-of-faxb-equal-to-frac-1a-cdot-faxbc)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just proceed by susbtitution:

Set $u=\frac x2$, so $\mathrm du=\frac12\mathrm d x\iff \mathrm d x=2\mathrm du$. So the integral becomes
$$\int\sin\frac x2\,\color{red}{\mathrm d x}=\int\sin u\cdot \color{red}{2\mathrm du}=2\int\sin u\,\mathrm du=2(-\cos u)=-2\cos u=-2\cos\frac x2.$$

Comment: Typographical error:  $\mathrm{d}u \color{red}{=} \frac{1}{2}\mathrm{d}x \iff \mathrm{d}x = 2\mathrm{d}u$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig: Fixed. Thanks for pointing the typo!

Answer (score 2):

Use substitution to simply integrate that function
$$I=\int \sin(x/2)\,dx$$
$$u=\frac x2 \implies du =\frac {dx}2 \implies dx=2\,du$$
$$I=\int \sin(x/2)\,dx=2\int \sin(u)\,du=-2\cos(u)=-2\cos(x/2).$$

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: yw @MukarramHaq ....

Answer (score 1):

$$\int \sin\left(\frac x2\right)\,dx$$

Now apply $u$-substitution:$u=\frac x2$

Then differentiate with respect to $x$. we get $du=\frac{dx}{2}$

$dx=2du$
$$=\int \sin(u)(2)\,du$$
$$=2\int \sin(u)\,du$$
$$=-2\cos(u)$$
Substitute back $u=\frac x2$

Then we get,
$$-2\cos\left(\frac x2\right)$$
$$\int \sin\left(\frac x2\right)\,dx=-2\cos\left(\frac x2\right)+C.$$

Answer (score 1):

$$I=\int{\sin\frac{x}{2}}dx$$
let$$u=\frac{x}{2}$$
so$$\frac{du}{dx}=\frac{1}{2}$$
and $$dx=2du$$
so $$I=2\int{\sin(u)du}=-2\cos(u)+c=-2\cos\frac{x}{2}+c$$
If in doubt, use substitution.

Comment: I've formatted the trigonometric functions and punctuation in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of integrating functions, think about what would happen if you differentiate the result of your integration.

You suppose $$\int f(x)\,dx=-\cos\left(\frac x2\right)$$
If so then:
$$f(x)=\frac 12\sin\left(\frac x2\right)$$
whereas your $f(x)=\sin\left(\frac x2\right)$

The factor of $2$ that is missing is the reason the correct integral is $-2\cos\left(\frac x2\right)$